# Yii2 Updating two fields with one dropdownlist

Tags: yii2

Basically I need one dropdown for updating two or more fields.

In the table "one" there are:

```
id, name, color
```

In table "two" there are:

```
id, some, others, fields, name, color
```

In the form realted to "two" model it is possible getting (and writing the value) of a listview populated from table "one":

```
$List1 = (ArrayHelper::map(One::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'));

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList($List1) ?>
```

How to get the corrisponding value "color" from table "one" as $List1 selected and write it in other field (inputfield in my case)?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'color')->textInput('value' => $List1->color) ?>
```